# Switch CB Radio mic with SPST button

Tags: transistors, switches, circuit-design, microphone

I'm a beginner with this type of electronics, but want to try this.

I have a CB radio with a 6-pin mic/controller. The pinout looks like this: [image: 6Pin CB mic pinout]

There is a DPDT switch in the mic that switches between receiving and transmitting. I sketched up this circuit with a few transistors and an external battery (3V), will this work to switch between those modes with a SPST button? It seems to work on the simulator but I'm not sure anymore and don't want to fry my radio.

[falstad.com circuit](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.0000049999999999999996+1.4391916095149893+50+5+43%0AR+352+96+352+64+0+0+40+12+0+0+0.5%0AR+512+96+512+64+0+0+40+12+0+0+0.5%0Ag+432+400+432+432+0%0At+480+320+512+320+0+1+-11.884961625256471+0.030319831012690507+100%0Ar+352+96+352+160+0+300%0Ar+512+96+512+160+0+300%0Aw+352+368+352+240+0%0Aw+512+368+512+336+0%0At+240+224+352+224+0+1+-2.636981292862231+0.6577005282453581+100%0Ax+493+48+523+51+0+24+TX%0Ax+332+51+365+54+0+24+RX%0Aw+128+272+128+320+0%0Aw+128+320+416+320+0%0At+192+272+240+272+0+1+-1.2579273105266335+0.11503837369013409+100%0Aw+240+288+240+400+0%0Aw+240+400+432+400+0%0Aw+432+400+432+368+0%0Aw+240+256+240+224+0%0Ar+240+224+240+160+0+10000%0As+64+400+64+272+0+1+true%0Av+240+400+64+400+0+0+40+3+0+0+0.5%0Aw+352+160+352+208+0%0Aw+512+160+512+304+0%0Ad+352+368+432+368+1+0.805904783%0Ad+512+368+432+368+1+0.805904783%0Aw+240+160+352+160+0%0Ar+192+272+128+272+0+10000%0Ar+416+320+480+320+0+10000%0Aw+128+272+64+272+0%0A)

The RX and TX pins are marked with +12V and a series resistor to give the circuit some load but I don't actually know the internal wiring of that, I just need to connect RX and TX pins to ground.

Also, can I connect the Mic to be always connected (the upper pole on the first schematic, that disconnects the mic when only receiving)? That way I wouldn't have to drive that with transistors as well.

*Bonus question: is there a way to wire this up so that I don't use any external power source?*

Comment: For the bonus part: Are you 100% sure that the pinout is actually correct? Usually, you'll get power source from the radio for the microphone, perhaps 7-8 V or so.

Comment: Unless you define the allowed DC specs for all inputs and outputs in each state, and take care with loop current noise, how can you decide if 12V is ok. Don't guess.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I included the wrong pinout originally (probably had too many tabs open after searching). I updated the question. The radio itself is a President Truman model [link](http://www.president-electronics.com/en/The_CB_Radios/Fiche_produit.php?REF=TXMU092) I can't seem to find out what exactly is the voltage of the RX/TX pins or if there is any(it seems they are pulled low on connection so I don't know if my circuit would actually work (I'm not that fluent in this type of electronics yet)